# ¿Decirle "narco" a alguien de Ecuador es un insulto?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, insultos, ecuador

Recién tuve una discusión con un tipo supuestamente de Ecuador que hizo acento colombiano y le comenté "A mi me sonó a narco" y el pobre se encabronó y me amenazó, cuando yo solo me refería a su audio imitando el acento colombiano. Quiero saber si es verdad que en Ecuador decir la palabra "narco" a alguien es insultarlo o solo me estaba timando para buscarme pleito.

Comment: Comentarle a alguien que te suena a narco me parece un insulto por todo el mundo al menos que lo conozcas bien

Comment: ¿Quisiste decirle que sonaba como un narco, o que sonaba como los protagonistas de la serie Narcos?

Comment: Decirle narco a quien sea es decirle eso. Igual que en cualquier idioma....

Comment: Eso es un insulto en cualquier parte del mundo